# Elasticsearch API not passing Json Dataset in the URL

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using elastic-search API for Python to query the data and plot the graph in our own application.
For some reason, the Json data (body/Param) was not posting along with my request URL. I get empty data object. Here is my code and the response.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json

from ssl import create_default_context
cafile="my.perm.pac"

context = create_default_context()

url = "https://mydev-elk.dev1.com/elasticsearch/logstash-browse-access-logs-*/"

data=
{

"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"match_all": {}
},
{
"range": {
"log_timestamp": {
"gte": 1526916192084,
"lte": 1526917092084,
"format": "epoch_millis"
}
}
}
],
"must_not": []
}
},

"size": 0,
"_source": {
"excludes": []
},

"aggregations": {

"2": {
  "date_histogram": {
    "field": "log_timestamp",
    "interval": "5s",
    "time_zone": "America/Chicago",
    "min_doc_count": 1
  }
}
}

}

es = Elasticsearch(
[url],
http_auth=(user', 'pass'),
scheme="https",
port=443,
ssl_context=context,
)

res = es.search(index="/logstash-browse-access-logs-*", body=data)

print(res)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following response:

```
{'took': 507, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 152, 'successful': 152, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
```

But when I use the URL in a browser I was able to get Json objects.

```
https://mydev-elk.dev1.com/elasticsearch/logstash-browse-access-logs-*/_search?source={"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match_all": {}},{"range": {"log_timestamp": {"gte": 1526916192084,"lte": 1526917092084,"format": "epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not": []}},"size": 0,"_source": {"excludes": []},"aggregations": {"2": {  "date_histogram": {    "field": "log_timestamp",    "interval": "5s",    "time_zone": "America/Chicago",   "min_doc_count": 1  }}}}
```

Can some one please help on what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to post an answer to my own questions, in case if someone else is looking

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'hostname or ip', 'port': 9200}], http_auth=('username', 'password'), maxsize=25)

data = es.search(request_timeout=30, index="your_index_name", body={"your Json query string as Json format"} )
print (data)
```

Comment: Sorry, How can I do that

Comment: Apologies, you need 15 reputation first. Have a look here once you do: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer